# How to update app version in WSO2 EMM?

Tags: wso2

I've successfully published an Android app on  WSO2 Enterprise Mobile Manager.
Now I want to update the app version, by uploading a new apk.

How can I do? I find no solution on the documentation.

Comment: There is a bug in the current version of EMM 1.1.0 which prevents you from uploading the same android app with different version. A public JIRA[1] has been created and the fix is commit to the git repo [2].
After applying the fix, please ensure the version is change in the manifest of your app. Then you will need to upload it as a new app into the publisher.

[1] - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-686
[2] - https://github.com/wso2-dev/product-emm/commit/02aa4418da643bc801db015927e2d19b085eb832

Comment: Please Note that in the current version, it does not support automatically push the new version to the devices which have the old android app installed.

Comment: @Nira, for Android, is there any way to Update an app on Wso2 EMM? I see that you can install/uninstall, but updating a currently installed app is not an option. Further, it seems that you cannot even determine the version of the app is installed on the user's device... So if you pushed an 'uninstall' then 'install' with the new version, as an admin, you couldn't know if it actually worked. How do you update an app? (Using Emm 1.1.0)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370213/wso2-emm-app-management-version-bug/33296670#33296670) for instructions on how to implement the patch they included in [EMM-686](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-686).