# wso2-emm app management version bug

Tags: git, wso2, wso2-iot

i encounter the bug [EMM-686](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-686) and i've seen the answer by Nira pointing to the jira and the github, but i don' find how i can apply the fix on my production (downloaded binaries from the website), is there a documentation for that ?
I don't understand why the binaries on the website don't include an up to date version of wso2-emm is there somewhere where i can found that ?

Obvisiously i already tried to apply manually the changes in the 2 files mentioned, and restart the server but no luck.

Comment: You mention something you read somewhere, please be clearer regarding this source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you apply the update they included in the patch attached to [EMM-686](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-686):

Open an explorer window and nagivate to **[EMM_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\themes\mobileapp**. There are two files we will need to modify in different folders found in this directory.

In **\js\mobileapp**, open **create.mobileapp.js** in your text editor of choice. Notepad++ is my preference.

Find this line of code: `$("#txtOSHidden").val($("#txtOS").val());` Now, create an empty line directly after it and paste this: `$("#version").val($("#txtVersion").val());`

Now go back to **\mobileapp** and navigate to the **\partials** folder. In your text editor, open **add-mobileapp.hbs**.

Find the following line of code and delete it: `<input type="hidden" name="version" value="1.0">`

In its place, add this line: `<input type="hidden" id="version" name="version" value="1.0">`

You should now be able to upload new versions of your apps without issue.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 provides official patches only for paid customers through [WSO2 support portal](http://wso2.com/support/), You either have to wait for the next release (in your case, it's 1.2.0) or have to manually apply the patch yourself.

The patch diff attached may be taken from the development branch in the middle of the development for 1.2.0, so, you might not be able apply it directly to EMM 1.1.0

Comment: i've seen the MDM 2.0.0 M6, but it seems not embedding the Mobile application Manager. So what you are saying,is that the binaries of the community edition don't include bugfixe at all, that's a bummer for me :(. For the manual fix, i've found the two files, and changed the line accordingly, and i've seen the same line as in the patches, but when i restart it has no effect whatsoever. is there somewhere a emm 1.2.0 M1 snapshot ?

Comment: MDM 2.0.0 Alpha will be released with Mobile App Manager