# wso2 emm apk version management using the WSO2 store

Tags: wso2-iot

I am testing WSO2-Emm system for managing our android mobile app. We have an app for taxi drivers. We deploy it using our tablets and a single gmail account. Our problem is that google allows up to 10 signed in devices for a single google account. 
I have tried to load the apk to the WSO2 store. The problem is that when I want to upload a new version of the same app I get a warning message saying that this APK already exists in the store. When I try to rename it and add it as a new apk it works. The problem is that when I go to App-Management, the application appears under 'installed'. The Emm system doesn't detect there is a new version. 
To be more specific, my question is is there a way to manage mobile application versions using the WSO2 store and not the google play store. 
If there is a way we can go on with this system. If not, we will stop testing it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've figured out how update an already installed app is by going to the **App Management** tab, selecting your latest version of the app in question, and hitting the install button under the **Roles** tab (NOT the Users tab). It will send the install command to any devices listed under roles you have checked, even if they already have the app installed. Keep in mind this will install the app on *all* the devices, even devices that already have the version you're trying to put out.

It looks like you already know about the patch on [EMM-686](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-686) that must be implemented in order to upload multiple versions of the same app to the Publisher. Just in case you want to confirm it's implemented correctly, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370213/wso2-emm-app-management-version-bug/33296670#33296670) for instructions on how to implement it.